# Managed components from app store will get into the package or not?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, package-install

I am working on a lightning app builder page. I installed some grid-based components from the app store. Will these managed components go into the package? or should we have to install these components in the existing orgs after upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are unmanaged components then you can include them in your package. If they are managed package components then you need to install these package first then you can install your package.